# Django and FCM to send push notifications

Tags: django, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

What's the correct way to use fcm-django using a custom Device-info model or a possibility to extend FCMDevice with more attributes.

For example, I need to store into the device info some additional fields like language, position  (lat/lng), app version, vendor etc.

I'm new for FCM but for me, at the moment, It's not very clear the device registration flow. 
My current project is a backend service for mobile apps. So, I have some REST service using djnago-rest-framework.

I already have an API to register/update a mobile device. Can I reuse it adding the FCM registration-id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your custom FCMDevice class by extending AbstactFCMDevice class as follows:

```
from fcm_django.models import AbstractFCMDevice
from django.db import models

class CustomFCMDevice(AbstractFCMDevice):
    language = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=False)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=False)
    app_version = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=False)
    ...
    ..
```

you can then use your custom class to get your queryset:

```
from custom_fcm_django.models import CustomFCMDevice

device = CustomFCMDevice.objects.all().first()

device.send_message(title="Title", body="Message", icon=..., data={"test": "test"})
```

you can use django rest framework APIView to create your API endpoints, for example:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class FCMDevicesListAPIView(APIView):

permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )

def get(self, request):
    queryset = CustomFCMDevice.objects.all()
    serializer = FCMDeviceSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```